# Relacionamento em Rails, como declarar no Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Tenho uma lista de estabelecimentos comerciais. Os usuários a princípio, não estão cadastrados em nenhum deles. Quando ele (o usuário) decide se cadastrar, é criado um relacionamento entre ele e o estabelecimento. Seria como o recurso 'adicionar amigo' do Facebook. Mas eis a questão:

Como ficaria o relacionamento das tabelas no banco de dados? E no Active Record pra ser mais específico? Seria uma espécie de relacionamento dinâmico (se é que isso existe)?

Comment: O usuário pode adicionar mais de um estabelecimento?

Comment: Sim @Ricardo, pode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos usar a seguinte nomenclatura:

- **Shop**: Estabelecimento comercial
- **CustomerLink**: Associação entre estabelecimento comercial e cliente
- **Customer**: Cliente

No `Active Record`, seu relacionamento ficaria assim:

```rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customerlinks
  has_many :customers, through: :customerlinks
end

class CustomerLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customerlinks
  has_many :shops, through: :customerlinks
end
```